# Ripple Effect is lost for child controls if [backgroundColor] Property is set for a mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Child Controls Loses Ripple Effect if [backgroundColor] property is set for mat-tab-group, is there any workaround.?

[Check this Stackblitz example to see the Issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-ripple-problem?file=app%2Fripple-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ripple effect is working but we are not able to see it as the `ripple color` is white. It is taking white color because you have set backgroundColor to primary and your primary color is blue which has foreground white. The ripple automatically takes this foreground color.

You can solve it by two methods

1. By providing color to `matRippleColor` attribute if your `backgroundColor` set to dark color, in your case its primary and warn.

   ```html
      <div class="div-style mat-elevation-z4" matRipple matRippleColor="rgba(0,0,0,.1)>Ripple</div>
   ```
2. By setting light `backgroundColor`. In your case its `accent`.

Comment: thanks... also could u please tell me how to get the current theme (dark/light)'s ripple color.. I'm using **mixin** and **scss** for component styles... and set it to the matRippleColor.